# How can we construct a matrix with size $n\times 2^n$ , i.e., each column vector is the vertex of the hyperplane generated by $[L,U]^n$?

Tags: matrices, matlab

In matlab, if we have two vectors L and U (with size n ), how can we efficiently construct a matrix with size $n\times 2^n$ , each column vector is the vertex of the hyperplane generated by $[L,U]^n$ ?

Comment: You might have more luck with a MATLAB tag over at [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).